# Access Alexa account email id in Alexa custom built skills conversation

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

We are building a banking related application involving Amazon Echo and Alexa. To make it workable, we need the email of the Alexa user to be access by ASK. Is there any way we can do that?

We checked and googled a lot but found nothing on it. Moreover Amazon documentation says it is currently not possible to access the mail ID without linking the user account. But to link a user account any kind of app is required which is basically to authenticate as the "Car-Fu service" example at Amazon documentation website suggests (https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/link-an-alexa-user-with-a-user-in-your-system.html) and we do not have any such thing.

Can any one please suggest is there any way we can get email ID of the Alexa user.

Comment: Yes, account linking *is* the right way to go about this. How do you have a banking system and no way to identify users?

Comment: you have to link the account, with that said if you don't want to link to your banking application directly i'd suggest creating a service for the sole purpose of identifying the users and authenticating them, alexa skills do not provide a way to extract user information with any other way

Comment: Tried linking my account with the custom skills as mentioned in the link : link. But even after doing this, I am still unable to get the email id from user. input session User object :class User { userId: amzn1.ask.account.AEIY57C76NSCWFOPYMFBW66VVPAZEOSAN74FKIKTUPZ5UH7EFT37MNUSSPVJRFJNIG6E2Z5FERYM4BH6MCYZGWJHUMBCFR3HIA3NPRHAUSXHH3MITU3GIKMK3C7IPPP6XHGHELR33U5UYQ7DSWQVALQRWVFLJKLCFXYGZTIUGHGUMLQNML22WAEOZNFF2LXHDLGFOPT5UHCSL7A accessToken: null permissions: null } There should be email details in the user object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone wondering how to access alexa account email id in alexa custom built skills conversation. Linking your account with alexa custom built skill is the right way.
I used following link: [https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/Tx3CX1ETRZZ2NPC/alexa-account-linking-5-steps-to-seamlessly-link-your-alexa-skill-with-login-with-amazon]
This post contain step by step process to get access token from alexa request and use it to get email id

Answer (score 0):

If it is a banking application then it is best to link the account. Since by this way you will be able to identify the user.

Or have a conversation with the user to authenticate the user and ask for information about the user. (This has to be done everytime and not a good user experience). Account linking is just a one time process.

Another option would be you can ask for permission from the user for his full address. 
https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/device-address-api.html

May be you can identify user based on is address. **But this is not a good solution because the address can vary.**

Comment: Tried linking my account with the custom skills as mentioned in the link : [link](https://www.jovo.tech/blog/alexa-login-with-amazon-email). But even after doing this, I am still unable to get the email id from user.


input session User object :class User {
userId: amzn1.ask.account.AEIY57C76NSCWFOPYMFBW66VVPAZEOSAN74FKIKTUPZ5UH7EFT37MNUSSPVJRFJNIG6E2Z5FERYM4BH6MCYZGWJHUMBCFR3HIA3NPRHAUSXHH3MITU3GIKMK3C7IPPP6XHGHELR33U5UYQ7DSWQVALQRWVFLJKLCFXYGZTIUGHGUMLQNML22WAEOZNFF2LXHDLGFOPT5UHCSL7A
accessToken: null
permissions: null
}

There should be email details in the user object.

Comment: Alexa will not send you the details of the user. The email id won't be in the request. The access token should not be null if account is linked. Using the access token you will be able to authenticate the user by sending it to your backend API and get the details of user (email, bank details) etc.

Comment: Sorry @Guru. I just realized Alexa will only send the access token. But the access token coming from my request is null. Can anyone help me with it why is it coming null in the request

Comment: It depends on the type of grant. Read https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/link-an-alexa-user-with-a-user-in-your-system.html#cert-user-acct-linking-setup.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone. Now I am able to link my account with my alexa custom skill set and get email id.
I used following link: [https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/Tx3CX1ETRZZ2NPC/alexa-account-linking-5-steps-to-seamlessly-link-your-alexa-skill-with-login-with-amazon]